# Appium Correct way to identify keypad is numpad or querty?

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, appium-java

Is there is another approach to identify keypad type (Native App).

```
public boolean isNumKeyPad(WebElement argWebElement){
        argWebElement.click();
        ((AndroidDriver)appiumDriver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.NUMPAD_1));   / value will be inserted in the text field, if num pad
        String currentText = argWebElement.getText();
        return currentText.equalsIgnoreCase("1");
}
```

Note: keypad is not visible by default, as I added below two capabilities.

```
setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.UNICODE_KEYBOARD, true);
setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.RESET_KEYBOARD, true);
```